PowerApp & Flow - upload XLS binary to API endpoint
I am new to Powerapps and need to figure out how to send a XLS file as a POST request to an API endpoint.
This is what a working CURL request would look like
curl -X 'POST' \
  'http://mydomain:5000/theEndpoint/' \
  -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' \
  -F 'uploaded_file=@MyXLSFile.xls'

How should the PowerApp + Flow look like that basically takes a file upload and sends it?
We figured to make a HTML upload form equivalent and assign a button push to run a Flow, but how do we hand over the data? Are there sample Flows somewhere? I am not finding anything useful beyond uploading files to Sharepoint.
